# Understand Object.create

Tags: javascript

After reading the [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) document. I did some test for it .
Here is my code . please review it.

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

Rectangle=Object.create(Shape);

Rectangle.move(); //?? why move function is not found ?
```

As the document says `Object.create(proto[,propertiesObject]);` `proto` should be the prototype of the newly-created object.
So, `Rectangle.prototype` should be equal with the `Shape`. but actually it is not. Apparently I didn't understand this part of document. and I still found `Rectangle.__proto__==Shape` is true. OK, Even `Rectangle.__proto__==Shape` is true , Why `Rectangle` can't find the `move` function? Is the `move` function not in the prototype chain?? I thought the `move` function is in the `Rectangle.__proto__.prototype`, It supposed to be found in the chain. Why can not? thanks.

Comment: I believe you wanted to use `Object.create(Shape.prototype)` instead

Comment: No, In my code . I just want to find out what happen to the `Object.create(Shape);` thanks.

Comment: When You read from a link or document Read carefully. The document clearly says
`Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);` 

the create method takes Protoype (Not class name or function) and Returns Prototype( not class name or function).

Comment: @JanDvorak You mean `Object.create(Shape);` is not allowed ?

Comment: I know the sample in the document works, But I just did some test for better understanding .. please give a reason of downvote...thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang it is allowed, but `Shape` is not one of those things you'd like to use as a prototype. `Shape` itself is just a constructor. `Shape.prototype` is a much more interesting prototype.

Comment: So, What happen to `Object.create(...);`if I pass a function instead of a prototype? thanks.

Comment: @JanDvorak Apparently It is allowed , Because no error was found in the firebug if I did so .

Comment: @Joe: `Object.create` accepts any object. Functions are objects too. So if you call `Object.create(Shape)`, then you are creating a new object that inherits from `Shape`, the function object. And that function does not have a `move` method (only if you did `Shape.move = ...`), but `Shape.prototype` does.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok ,If it creates a new object inherited from `Shape`, It should find the `move`, but actually it does't. Why?

Comment: I just explained that. `Shape` does not have a property `move` (`Shape.move` is `undefined`). The property `move` is defined on `Shape.prototype`, not `Shape`.

Comment: @FelixKling hm...If `move` is not found in the `Shape`, it will be found in `Shape.prototype`, That is the prototype inheritance. Just like the code `Rectangle=new Shape()` is creating a new object inherited from `Shape` which will find the `move` function. did I misunderstand something ? thanks.

Comment: *"did I misunderstand something"* Yes. With `Rectangle=new Shape()` you are creating a new object which inherits from **`Shape.prototype`**. `Shape` is just used to create the object for you, but it does not inherit from `Shape`. That's why the function is called *constructor function*. In `Rectangle=Object.create(Shape)` OTOH, you are creating a new object which inherits from `Shape`.

Comment: wow....I think that is the point ...let me think about it for a while ...

Comment: @FelixKling `Rectangle=Object.create(Shape) OTOH, you are creating a new object which inherits from Shape`, Why the `Rectangle` can't find the method `stop` defined in the `Shape` , if I defined like this `this.stop=funtion(){...}` in the `Shape`.thanks.

Comment: Because you are never *executing* `Shape` and `this` does not refer to `Shape` itself. You would have to do `Shape.stop = ...`. And for that matter, `Shape` does not even have to be a function. All that `Object.create` does is basically `var obj = {}; obj.__proto__ = Shape;`. So if `obj.stop` cannot be found, it will be looked up on `obj.__proto__.stop`, which is the same as `Shape.stop`.

Comment: I see . `Rectangle=Object.create(Shape)` doesn't call the `Shape` function as the constructor. right ?

Comment: Ok. So, What is the exactly use of the `__proto__`, Does it have something to do with the chain? It is confused...

Comment: @FelixKling  I found the issue , I said `this.stop` but you said `Shape.stop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype must be an actual object.  In this case, you should pass Shape's prototype, not the Shape function.

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

Rectangle=Object.create(Shape.prototype, {a:1});

Rectangle.move(); // it will call now
Rectangle.a; // 1
Rectangle.x; // NaN ???
Rectangle.y; // NaN ???
```

Note that `Object.create()` is not the same as using the `new` keyword - that might be what you were looking for instead.

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

Rectangle=new Shape;

Rectangle.move(1,2); // works properly now
Rectangle.a; // undefined, we never made one
Rectangle.x; // 1
Rectangle.y; // 2
```

As Javascript actually looks up the constructor and its `.prototype` to find the prototype recursively, it won't look up Shape's prototype as it was not directly set nor was the `new` constructor used to create `Rectangle`:

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

Rectangle = Object.create(Shape);
Rectangle.constructor; // Function()
Rectangle.constructor.prototype; // That's Function.prototype
/* as you can see Shape.prototype is never touched by the prototype chain */

Rectangle.__proto__; // Shape(), not the prototype (doesn't have any direct properties on it)

Rectangle.move(1,2); // TypeError: Rectangle.move is not a function
Rectangle.a; // does not exist
Rectangle.x; // function never called on Rectangle, so also doesn't exist
Rectangle.y; // function never called on Rectangle, so also doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this will help you to understand a little bit more:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwYPG6vreJg&feature=player_detailpage#t=739s

Here he explains that it doesn't work same as you said. 
Your argument that

> I thought the `move` function is in the `Rectangle.__proto__.prototype`

is correct. You can find `move` as `Rectangle.__proto__.prototype.move` but it **doesn't implies** that you can find it as `Rectangle.move`. Prototype chain is interrupted. I think that it is detaily described in the video.

Try to think about these parts of code:

```
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

Shape.__proto__.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

Rectangle=Object.create(Shape);

Rectangle.move();
```

or:

```
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

Rectangle=Object.create(Shape);

Rectangle.prototype.move();
```

(x and y are still incorrect in these cases, but you weren't asking about them ;) )